# Laravel - Blade not loading in the browser

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have a new Laravel project that doesn't seem to load Blade correctly.

I've looked over the documentation at Laravel.com, watched videos on Laracasts, and scanned Stackoverflow as much as possible, but I still haven't been able to figure it out. Can you help?!

Okay, here is what I have so far:

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'RentsController@index',
    'as' => 'layouts.index'
    ]);
```

**RentsController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $rents = DB::table('rents')
        ->orderByDesc('price')
        ->get();
    return view('layouts.index', ['rents' => $rents]);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

**search.blade.php**

```
@extends ('layouts.index')

@section ('content')
    <p>title</p>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($rents as $rent)
        <li>{{ $rent->price }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

**File structure:**

views -> layouts -> index.blade.php
views -> search.blade.php

So, whenever I paste the code within @section('content') directly into the file index.blade.php, it works perfectly. However, as I have it right now, nothing from search.blade.php appears in the browser and there is no error either.

Any idea what it could be?

Thanks guys!! I really appreciate any help, tips, questions, comments that you could provide. :)

Comment: Given the way you have structured your files you have to load the search view from your controller:view('search',...

Comment: Otherwise you will want to check out how to load the search partial with @include

Comment: Thanks @alariva, you're absolutely right. I was loading the wrong file! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I don't know why you specified your layout in routes and controller.   It's enough to return your page template in the controller:

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/','RentsController@index');
```

**RentsController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $rents = DB::table('rents')
        ->orderByDesc('price')
         ->get();
    return view('search', compact('rents'));
}
```

In using layouts, it's enough to use `@extends ('layouts.index')` and the template will identify it.

Comment: Nice! Actually, for Web.php, I had initially had this. What did work, however, in the end, was "return view('search', compact('rents'));" -> perhaps I was going for the wrong file in the end... for the overview and not the search page itself. Thanks @Irandoust!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I explained with your current code for more clear demonstration. Glad it helped :)